# HttpWebRequest's response don't show UTF-8 symbols

Tags: c#, utf-8, httpwebrequest, utf8-decode

I have simple code for getting response from websites, but there is one small problem. I am trying to get response from Russian website and from one website I unknown symbols and from other I get normal text. Where might be problem ?

Response from: www.kinopoisk.ru

> ������ � ����...

Response from: www.yandex.ru

> Греция - Чехия. 1:2...

```
    HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://");
    http.Timeout = 30000;
    http.KeepAlive = true;
    http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    http.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0";
    http.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    http.Proxy = null;

    WebResponse response = http.GetResponse();
    Stream istream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(istream);

    Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());

    reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`kinopoisk.ru` is encoded as `WINDOWS-1251`  (you can see this in the `Content-Type` header).

You need to pass `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)` to the StreamReader to decode that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a charset issue. If you want to get the character set of response of your request HttpWebResponse class provides us a property named CharacterSet. This property returns the string type value.

```
myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
myWebRequest.Method = "GET";
myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
string str = myWebResponse.CharacterSet;
```

If you want to get that which encoding method is used to encode the response, for this purpose we have a property of HttpWebRequest class named ContentEncoding. This property returns string value.

```
myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
myWebRequest.Method = "GET";
myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
string str = myWebResponse.ContentEncoding;
```